# How to return value to user from a Search Help Exit

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I have a Search Help with many fields to be displayed to the user in order to apply values. I want to get 3 fields `APOFASI`, `SKOPOS`, `KATDANL` from the user.

In the `CALLCONTROL-STEP = SELECT` in the exit FM, I want to get these values in variables and then to make some selects and find another field `APOFASISAP`.
I am trying to pass back to the selection fields of the search help the field APOFASSISAP, but the APOFASI field seems to be blank.
The code is:

```
  TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_apofasisap_tr,
          apofasisap_tr TYPE zglk_sap_afopasi,
         END OF ty_apofasisap_tr.

  DATA: it_apofasisap_tr TYPE TABLE OF ty_apofasisap_tr,
        wa_apofasisap_tr LIKE LINE OF it_apofasisap_tr.

  DATA: lv_apofasi TYPE zglk_kyanr_ap,
        lv_skopos  TYPE zskopos,
        lv_katdanl TYPE zsl_cat_dan,
        lv_apofasisap_arx TYPE zglk_sap_afopasi.        
    lv_apofasi = wa_shlp_selopt-low.
    ls_result-apofasi = ''.
    IF lv_apofasi <> ''.
      wa_shlp_selopt-low = ''.
      MODIFY shlp-selopt FROM wa_shlp_selopt INDEX sy-tabix.
    ENDIF.

    READ TABLE shlp-selopt INTO wa_shlp_selopt WITH KEY shlpfield = 'SKOPOS'.

    lv_skopos = wa_shlp_selopt-low.

    READ TABLE shlp-selopt INTO wa_shlp_selopt WITH KEY shlpfield = 'KATDANL'.

    lv_katdanl = wa_shlp_selopt-low.

    SELECT SINGLE apofasisap INTO lv_apofasisap_arx
      FROM zsl_glk_apof
      WHERE apofasi = lv_apofasi.

    SELECT * FROM zsl_glk_apof_tr
      WHERE apofasisap_trp = lv_apofasisap_arx.

      wa_apofasisap_tr-apofasisap_tr = zsl_glk_apof_tr-apofasisap_tr.
      APPEND wa_apofasisap_tr TO it_apofasisap_tr.

    ENDSELECT.
    wa_shlp_selopt-shlpname  = 'ZAPOF_TROP'.
    wa_shlp_selopt-shlpfield = 'APOFASISAP'.
    wa_shlp_selopt-sign      = 'I'.
    wa_shlp_selopt-option    = 'EQ'.
    wa_shlp_selopt-low       = wa_apofasisap_tr-apofasisap_tr.
    APPEND wa_shlp_selopt TO shlp-selopt.
```

This code does not replace/add the values to the appropriate fields.
Can someone help on this?

PS. Let me add another code that I wrote with the help of internet. It is in the STEP of DISPLAY.

```
IF callcontrol-step = 'DISP'.
TYPES: BEGIN OF ls_result,
      apofasi LIKE zsl_glk_apof-apofasi,
      apofasidate LIKE zsl_glk_apof-apofasidate,
      apofasisap LIKE zsl_glk_apof-apofasisap,
      apofasi_trp_x LIKE zsl_glk_apof-apofasi_trp_x,
      apofasi_tr_x LIKE zsl_glk_apof-apofasi_tr_x,
      fek LIKE zsl_glk_apof-fek,
      katdanl LIKE zsl_glk_apof-katdanl,
      reference LIKE zsl_glk_apof-reference,
      skopos LIKE zsl_glk_apof-skopos,
      thema LIKE zsl_glk_apof-thema,
      type_desc LIKE zsl_glk_apof-type_desc,
      ya_first LIKE zsl_glk_apof-ya_first,
END OF ls_result.

DATA: lt_result TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ls_result.

CLEAR: lt_result, record_tab, record_tab[].
* Read the value that user gave
READ TABLE shlp-selopt INTO wa_shlp_selopt
                        WITH KEY shlpfield = 'APOFASI'.

lv_apofasi = wa_shlp_selopt-low.

IF lv_apofasi <> ''.

  * Clear this value
  wa_shlp_selopt-low = ''.
  MODIFY shlp-selopt FROM wa_shlp_selopt INDEX sy-tabix.
ENDIF.

* Find the number starting APOFASISAP from the APOFASI text
SELECT SINGLE apofasisap INTO lv_apofasisap_arx
  FROM zsl_glk_apof
  WHERE apofasi = lv_apofasi.

IF sy-subrc = 0.

 * Find the APOFASISAPs which changes the starting one and display the 
  *fields
  SELECT a~apofasi a~apofasidate a~apofasisap
         a~apofasi_tr_x a~apofasi_trp_x
         a~thema a~fek a~reference a~ya_first
      INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_result
    FROM zsl_glk_apof AS a INNER JOIN zsl_glk_apof_tr AS b
                            ON a~apofasisap = b~apofasisap_tr
    WHERE b~apofasisap_trp = lv_apofasisap_arx.

  IF sy-subrc = 0.
    *Pass them to display the result.
    CALL FUNCTION 'F4UT_RESULTS_MAP'
      EXPORTING
    *   SOURCE_STRUCTURE         =
        apply_restrictions       = 'X'
       TABLES
         shlp_tab                 = shlp_tab
         record_tab               = record_tab
         source_tab               = lt_result
       CHANGING
         shlp                     = shlp
         callcontrol              = callcontrol
      EXCEPTIONS
        illegal_structure        = 1
        OTHERS                   = 2
               .
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
              WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
    ENDIF.
  ENDIF.
  FREE lt_result.

ENDIF.
```

It says NO VALUES FOR THIS SELECTION. The table lt_result contains 11 records.

Thanks again.

Comment: This is just an arbitrary snippet of code referring to some custom objects nobody but you knows anything about and without a clear description where it is called and what exactly is going wrong. Please try to provide a [MCVE]https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have created a SH that displays 4 fields to the user and waiting to fill 3 of them. The fields that the user have to be fullfill are: APOFASI-SKOPOS-KATDAL. So when the user press enter the value of CALLCONTROL-STEP is becaming SELECT and in the EXIT FM I want to find the 4th field APOFASISAP and pass it to the appropriate field of the Search-Helps field. I also want to delete the value of the field APOFASI and proceed with the fields APOFASISAP-SKOPOS-KATDANL and display the appropriate records to the user in order to select one.    This is the only code in FM (missing only the DATA VAR).

Comment: Your `F4UT_RESULTS_MAP` call seems fine. Does `IF sy-subrc = 0` check passes?

Comment: I did and the sy-subrc is 0. I noticed that the structure record_tab is full and the table is empty (record_tab[]). Is there any way to fill it?

Comment: @ekekakos, it is empty because you clear it in DISP event.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the forespeakers, that provided code is a mess, from which nothing can be figured out.

First of all, use **DISP** event in SHELP FM exit, not **SELECT**.

Secondly, you fill the wrong table (or do not show us right filling in the snippet above). In order to pass values back to user you should modify a `RECORD_TAB` table.

Your code should look something like this (joined selections from `zsl_glk_apof` and `zsl_glk_apof_tr` tables):

```
CHECK callcontrol-step = 'DISP'.
DATA: ls_selopt TYPE ddshselopt.  "loc str for shlp-selopt
DATA: BEGIN OF ls_record.
      INCLUDE STRUCTURE seahlpres.
DATA: END OF ls_record.
DATA: lv_glk_apof_tr TYPE zsl_glk_apof_tr-apofasisap_tr.

LOOP AT shlp-selopt INTO ls_selopt.

* finding SKOPOS and KATDANL values
  CASE ls_selopt-shlpfield.
   WHEN 'SKOPOS'.
    lv_skopos = ls_selopt-low.
   WHEN 'KATDANL'.
    lv_katdanl = ls_selopt-low.
   WHEN OTHERS.
  ENDCASE.

  * doing smth

  * finding some stuff from Z-tables
  SELECT SINGLE tr~apofasisap_tr
  FROM zsl_glk_apof AS ap
  JOIN zsl_glk_apof_tr AS tr
   ON ap~apofasisap = tr~apofasisap_trp
  INTO lv_glk_apof_tr
   WHERE ap~apofasi = lv_apofasi.
ENDLOOP.

* modify record_tab with the found value lv_glk_apof_tr
LOOP AT record_tab INTO ls_record.
  ls_record-string+25(5) = lv_glk_apof_tr.  "field shift should be based on your values
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: I will try your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Hello and thanks all for your valuable help.
Finally I did it as follow:

```
  if callcontrol-step = 'SELECT'.
get parameter id 'ZAP' field p_apofasi.
get parameter id 'ZSK' field p_skopos.
get parameter id 'ZKATDANL' field p_katdanl.

select single apofasisap into lv_apofasisap_arx
  from zsl_glk_apof
  where apofasi = p_apofasi and
        katdanl = p_katdanl and
        skopos  = p_skopos.

select * into corresponding fields of table it_apofasisap_tr
  from zsl_glk_apof_tr
  where apofasisap_trp = lv_apofasisap_arx.

* Display the results to the user
types: begin of ls_result,
        apofasi like zsl_glk_apof-apofasi,
        apofasidate like zsl_glk_apof-apofasidate,
        apofasisap like zsl_glk_apof-apofasisap,
        apofasi_trp_x like zsl_glk_apof-apofasi_trp_x,
        apofasi_tr_x like zsl_glk_apof-apofasi_tr_x,
        katdanl like zsl_glk_apof-katdanl,
        skopos like zsl_glk_apof-skopos,
        type_desc like zsl_glk_apof-type_desc,
  end of ls_result.

data: lt_result type standard table of ls_result.

clear: lt_result, record_tab, record_tab[].

* Fill all the fields of the Search-Help with the data according to the
*selections of the user.
select apofasi apofasidate apofasisap
       apofasi_tr_x apofasi_trp_x
       katdanl skopos type_desc
    into corresponding fields of table lt_result
  from zsl_glk_apof
  for all entries in it_apofasisap_tr
  where apofasisap = it_apofasisap_tr-apofasisap_tr and
        apofasi_tr_x = 'X'. "lv_apofasi_tr_x.


call function 'F4UT_RESULTS_MAP'
  tables
    shlp_tab          = shlp_tab
    record_tab        = record_tab
    source_tab        = lt_result
  changing
    shlp              = shlp
    callcontrol       = callcontrol
  exceptions
    illegal_structure = 1
    others            = 2.

if sy-subrc = 0.
  callcontrol-step = 'DISP'.
else.
  callcontrol-step = 'EXIT'.
endif.
endif.
```

Regards
Elias